# Unable to connect to Cloud SQL (through Auth Proxy) from Cloud Run

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-code

I am trying to access my Cloud SQL database (PostgreSQL) through a Cloud Run application (Node.js) that I am developing locally (using Cloud Code as part of the VS Code extension).

I am able to access the database through the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy in my terminal (using `psql "host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 sslmode=disable dbname=*** user=***"`) but have never been able to successfully connect from my local Cloud Run.

The Cloud SQL database is set up as a connection in my Cloud Run project.

I have tried (and failed) with two ways to try and connect:

1. **Using the instance connection name**: When I do something like this:

```js
const pg = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    user: '...', 
    password: '...',
    database: '...',
    host: '/cloudsql/...',
  },
  debug: true,
});
```

I get the following error:

```
connect ENOENT /cloudsql/.../.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

2. **Using local host and port**: When I do something like this:

```js
const pg = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    user: '...', 
    password: '...',
    database: '...',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432,
  },
  debug: true,
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
```

Comment: Does your host look like `/cloudsql/myproject:us-central1:myinstance`?

Comment: To clarify: - does you Cloud SQL proxy keep running when you develop your Cloud Run app locally? - is your app able to connect to the database when it runs locally without Cloud Run emulator in Cloud Code (usually you can also run CR Local application locally depending on how many GCP services you use)

Comment: @enocom, yes -- that is what I've been trying to use for the host, but I don't think the file is actually being mounted as part of my Cloud Run instance (on my local development machine)

Comment: @IvanPortyankin, the Cloud SQL proxy is running and I can connect to to it directly from my terminal, but I am unable to connect at all from my Cloud Run app running locally via Cloud Code

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Code local Cloud Run implementation doesn't support Cloud SQL at the moment. One way to add Cloud SQL Proxy running next to your Cloud Run application is to add it as a *side car* to the container that Cloud Code deploys during Cloud Run local development session. Try the following:

1. Start Cloud Code `Cloud Run: Run Locally` session
2. Wait for the application to build and start, and endpoints to be available
3. At this moment, your application is running in minikube as a container (in a separate namespace called `cloud-run-dev-internal`), and deployment name matches your Cloud Run service name.
4. Create a *YAML patch file* which will start Cloud SQL Proxy next to your application so it will be available locally (via localhost):

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cloud-sql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy
        command:
        - "/cloud_sql_proxy"

        # By default, the proxy will write all logs to stderr. In some
        # environments, anything printed to stderr is consider an error. To
        # disable this behavior and write all logs to stdout (except errors
        # which will still go to stderr), use:
        - "-log_debug_stdout"

        # Replace DB_PORT with the port the proxy should listen on
        # Defaults: MySQL: 3306, Postgres: 5432, SQLServer: 1433
        - "-instances=my-project:my-region:my-instance=tcp:3306"
```

5. Save this as `cloudsql-proxy-patch.yaml`. Apply this patch file the following way:
   `kubectl patch deployment {your_cloud_run_service_name} --patch-file cloudsql-proxy-patch.yaml --context cloud-run-dev-internal`
6. After some time Cloud SQL proxy should be running. To diagnose, you can use Kubernetes Explorer and look inside `cloud-run-dev-internal` namespace and see if your pod has both your application and Cloud SQL Proxy side car container.

The rest depends on how you configure your Cloud SQL proxy locally. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#run_the_as_a_sidecar for more details on how to setup proxy as a sidecar.